# Apache LDAP Authentication Keeps Giving HTTP 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ldap

I'm trying to perform LDAP authentication using .htaccess with Apache. However, I keep getting 500 errors... I'm not very knowledgable about LDAP, so I might be doing something really stupid (e.g., my URL may be wrong), so I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPURL ldap://myLDAPServer:389/o=myRootName?uid
require valid-user
```

I'm afraid I'm not sure exactly which version of Apache2 is running (and, likewise, I don't have access to the server logs), but I know that mod_authnz_ldap is available. As for the LDAP instance, I think it's a Novel eDirectory server... Sorry to be so vague.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try connecting with a command-line LDAP client and doing a basic `ldapsearch`?

It's possible that you need to use an SSL bind, or set your base DN to something else, but without more information it's impossible to be sure what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Playing around with LDAP tools (jXplorer and Microsoft ldp) I found that I could locate my `uid` by doing a subtree search on `o=myRootName`, without an SSL bind. Likewise, I could locate my `uid` by doing a base search with the tree as a base DN (e.g., `ou=STAFF,ou=DEPT,ou=SUB,o=myRootName`). I tried this latter approach in the `.htaccess` and I still get the same problem :(

Comment: I have just built a quick PHP LDAP search and authentication script (running on the same server) and it works fine. It searches `o=myRootName` for `cn=myUserID` and, if it finds the user, returns its base DN in the tree and attempts to bind with my password... Given that this is working, does it help debug the `.htaccess` problem as, if possible, I'd prefer to use this over rolling my own login system.

Comment: @Xophmeister Okay, so it's not the parameters that are the issue. The options you gave are good, so the next step is to contact someone who does have access to the server logs and see what they say is the problem.

Comment: ...Ultimately, I've decided to go with a PHP login system rather than `.htaccess`. It was much easier this way! +1 for your help, all the same :)